# I created an array of pictureBoxes how can i register for an event to all the pictureBoxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

The code:

```
pbs = new PictureBox[8];
for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
{
    pbs[i] = new PictureBox();
    pbs[i].MouseEnter += Form1_MouseEnter;
    pbs[i].MouseLeave += Form1_MouseLeave;
    pbs[i].Size = new Size(100, 100);
    pbs[i].Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 60);
    pbs[i].Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    pbs[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    Panel p = i < 4 ? panel1 : panel2;
    p.Controls.Add(pbs[i]);
    pbs[i].BringToFront();
}
```

I did:

```
pbs[i].MouseEnter +=
```

And when i clicked TAB it did: Form1_MouseEnter
It's not what i wanted.

I want that when i move with the mouse over each of the pictureBoxes area it will do something.
One event for all the pictureBoxes. 
If i moved over pictureBox1 do something...pictureBox2 the same...

How can i do it ? I don't want to create 8 events for each pictureBox but one enter event for all.

Comment: I thought when i click TAB it will add: pbs_MouseEnter or something like that.

Comment: you can as well type the handler name yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need simply write

```
pbs[i].MouseEnter += globalMouseEnterEvent;
```

of course you need to have a `globalMouseEnterEvent` somewhere in your code

```
public void globalMouseEnterEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ....
}
```

However, another piece of information is needed when your work with event shared between numerous controls. You need to recognize the control that triggers the event. The control instance is passed using the `sender` parameter that you can cast to your appropriate control type, but what is needed is to give a unique identifier to your control. Like setting the Tag or Name properties when you build the control

```
for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
{
  .....
  pbs[i].Tag = "PB" + i.ToString()
  ...
}
```

so in the MouseEnter code you could write

```
public void globalMouseEnterEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox p = sender as PictureBox;
    if(p.Tag.ToString() == "PB1")
        .....
    else if ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use form1_event , copy it's code and rename it

```
pbs[i].MouseEnter += yourEventName
```

it's enough

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is absolute correct, you attach the handler to the event of each control in 
turn, so that the same handler works for every `PictureBox`.

I guess your problem is that the method VS creates is named `Form1_MouseEnter`. This is completely irrelevant, what determines what a method will handle is the `+=` operator, not its name. Just try to run your original code and it will do what you want.

It seems to be a bug in the C# editor though, as it should have named the automatically generated handler something more appropriate, but anyway, you can rename the method afterwards to reflect its true meaning.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried to apply the tips from the others to your code:

```
pbs = new PictureBox[8];
for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
{
    pbs[i] = new PictureBox();
    pbs[i].MouseEnter += Picturebox_MouseEnter;
    pbs[i].MouseLeave += PictureBox_MouseLeave;
    pbs[i].Name = string.Concat("PB", i); //Added to identify each picturebox
    pbs[i].Size = new Size(100, 100);
    pbs[i].Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 60);
    pbs[i].Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    pbs[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    Panel p = i < 4 ? panel1 : panel2;
    p.Controls.Add(pbs[i]);
    pbs[i].BringToFront();
}
```

And the handlers:

```
private void Picturebox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = sender as PictureBox;
    if (pb != null)
    {
        if (pb.Name == "PB2")
        {
            //Do PB2 specific task
        }
        //Your code when mouse enters one of the pictureboxes
        //Use Name property to determine wich one, if needed
    }
}

private void PictureBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Your code when mouse leaves one of the pictureboxes
    //Use Name property to determine wich one, if needed
}
```